# Inputting scraped data into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

Heyo,

So I built a working scraper and added the file to my app. I am now trying to take the information in the scraper and place it in my database. I am attempting to use the find_or_create method but I keep getting the following error.

```
 breads_scraper.rb:49:in `block in summary': uninitialized constant Scraper::Bread    (NameError)   
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-  1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
from breads_scraper.rb:24:in `map'
from breads_scraper.rb:24:in `summary'
from breads_scraper.rb:57:in `<class:Scraper>'
from breads_scraper.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

My code looks like the following. My theory is that I am using find_or_create incorrectly, or the file doesn't know how to reach the bread method and controller.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

url = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breads"))

class Scraper 

def initialize
  @url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breads"
  @nodes = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))

end

def summary

  bread_data = @nodes

  breads = bread_data.css('div.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable tr') 
     bread_data.search('sup').remove

    bread_hashes = breads.map {|x| 

      if content = x.css('td')[0]
        name = content.text
      end
       if content = x.css('td a.image').map {|link| link ['href']}
        image =content[0]
      end
      if content = x.css('td')[2]
        type = content.text
      end
       if content = x.css('td')[3]
        country = content.text
      end
       if content = x.css('td')[4]
        description =content.text
      end

   {
      :name => name,
      :image => image,
      :type => type,
      :country => country,
      :description => description,
    }
    Bread.find_or_create(:title => name, :description => description, :image_url => image, :country_origin => country, :type => type)

        }

   end


bready = Scraper.new
bready.summary
puts "atta boy"
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're expecting your rails environment to be available, which depends on how you're running the script.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can load the class? Thanks

Comment: From a rake task with the environment set. You can leave out the requires too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the the scraper from a rake task.

**lib/tasks/scraper.rake**

```
  namespace :app do
    desc "Scrape breads"
    task :scrape_breads => :environment do
      Scraper.new.summary
    end
  end
```

Now, you can run the rake task as follows:

```
rake app:scrape_breads
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Bread class is not loaded.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the issue. I will be honest though, I am not sure how to load it...